# Busqueda interna de menu

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un menu en html con una cantidad x de listas que a su vez tienen etiquetas a, como puedo implementar un buscador, para que muestre los enlaces "a" ya que son bastantes, y me redireccionen a el enlace seleccionado?

Tengo:

```
<li class="lista">
  <a href="#">enlace0</a> 
</li> 
<li class="lista"> 
  <a href="#">enlace1</a> 
</li>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade aunque sea un pequeño ejemplo de tu código para que sepamos mejor como está estructurado el menú. Además, incluye detalles como ¿quieres buscar por el texto del enlace?¿o por el href?¿cómo quieres que se muestre?¿si hay varios, cómo sabes donde redireccionar?

Comment: Digamos que tengo:

40 enlaces <a>
como podria implementar un buscador que me ahorrre el trabajo de buscar los enlaces manualmente?
no importa si los busca por texto o por id

Comment: ¿Usas algún framework/biblioteca (p.e. jQuery) o sólo JavaScript?

Comment: estaba utilizando jquery ya que html5 no es un estantart y no puedo ocuparlo en este caso, tengo algo asi.

$(document).ready(function(){  var availableTags = [
"Physical Inventory 2016"=,  
"PI Graphs and Reports",  
"PI Control Desk",  
"CIM Ideas System",  
"Global Label Printer",  
"Doublets Redundant/Global"
];
$("#tags").autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});

Comment: ahora eso me hace la busqueda, pero no me redirecciona a ningun lado, solo es texto que coincide con el nombre de las etiquetas

Comment: Entonces realmente lo que quieres es cambiar el autocomplete de jQuery UI para que se ajuste a las opciones del menú, ¿no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo simple siguiendo este algoritmo:

- Agregar un controlador del evento keyup a la caja de búsqueda
- Cada vez que cambie el valor
- Atravesar la lista del menú
- Analizar el contenido para ver si cumple el patrón de búsqueda

  - Si lo cumple: muestra el elemento
  - Si no lo cumple, esconde el elemento

Un ejemplo básico usando jQuery:

```js
$("#buscar").on("keyup", function() {

  var patron = $(this).val();

  // si el campo está vacío
  if (patron == "") {

    // mostrar todos los elementos
    $(".lista").css("display", "list-item");

    // si tiene valores, realizar la búsqueda
  } else {

    // atravesar la lista
    $(".lista").each(function() {

      if ($(this).text().indexOf(patron) < 0) {
        // si el texto NO contiene el patrón de búsqueda, esconde el elemento
        $(this).css("display", "none");
      } else {
        // si el texto SÍ contiene el patrón de búsqueda, muestra el elemento
        $(this).css("display", "list-item");
      }

    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="buscar" />
<ul>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 0</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 1</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 2</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 3</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 4</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 5</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 6</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 7</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 8</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 9</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 10</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 11</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 12</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#">enlace 13</a></li>
</ul>
```

Éste es un ejemplo muy básico (sólo busca cadenas literales), podrías hacerlo más complejo (y efectivo) añadiendo expresiones regulares y comodines.

---

Después de leer con más detenimiento los comentarios a la pregunta y en esta respuesta, parece que lo que quieres conseguir es personalizar el autocomplete (supongo que usas el de jQuery UI) para que se ajuste a las opciones del menú.

En ese caso, el código de arriba no te va a servir de mucho y lo que necesitas es hacer uso del Autocomplete con datos personalizados (*custom data*). Puedes leer [más información sobre esto en el sitio web de jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data).

Voy a crear un pequeño ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo partiendo del código que compartiste en uno de los comentarios:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var availableTags = [ "Physical Inventory 2016", "PI Graphs and Reports", "PI Control Desk", "CIM Ideas System", "Global Label Printer", "Doublets Redundant/Global" ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({ source: availableTags }); 
});
```

Ahora mismo estás generando un array con valores, pero jQuery UI te permite crear un array de objetos donde podrías usar los datos que quieras. En tu caso los pasos a seguir serían:

1. Antes de llamar al autocomplete, crea un almacén de datos vacío (un array)
2. Atraviesa la lista de menús y para cada elemento:

   - Lee la URL del enlace
   - Lee el texto del enlace
   - Añádelos como un objeto (con propiedades *label* para el texto y *value* para el valor) al almacén de datos.
3. Crea el autocomplete como:

   - Indicando en el *source* el array del paso 1
   - Definiendo tu propio método de selección que redirigirá a la URL del campo seleccionado.

Aquí dejo una pequeña demo comentada (que en lugar de hacer la redirección muestra un mensaje de alerta con la URL a la que habría que redirigir):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // comenzamos con un contenedor de datos vacio
  var availableTags = [];

  // para cada elemento de la lista
  $(".lista").each(function() {
    // crea un valor personalizado con label (texto) y value (href)
    var el = { "label": $(this).text(), "value": $(this).find("a").attr("href") };
    // añádelo a la lista
    availableTags.push(el);
  });

  // ahora que tenemos ya los datos, crea el autocomplete
  $("#autocompletar").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags, // indica tu fuente de datos
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      // muestra el nombre indicada en el label
      $( "#autocompletar" ).val( ui.item.label );
      // redircciona al la url indicada en el value
      alert("Redireccionar a " + ui.item.value);
      // location.assign( ui.item.value );
      return false;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="autocompletar" />

<ul id="menu">
  <li class="lista"><a href="#1">Elemento 1</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#2">Elemento 2</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#3">Elemento 3</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#4">Elemento 4</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#5">Elemento 5</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#6">Elemento 6</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#7">Elemento 7</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#8">Elemento 8</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#9">Elemento 9</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#10">Elemento 10</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#11">Elemento 11</a></li>
  <li class="lista"><a href="#12">Elemento 12</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: exelente condigo muchas gracias, pero busco mas bien algo como... buscar, seleccionar y agregar el texto al input text, despues precionar al  boton para abrir la nueva pagina.
como el buscador de google pero con los elementos de lista en mi index

Comment: Por cierto, si esta respuesta realmente no responde a la pregunta no deberías marcarla como aceptada. Otras personas que pudieran darte una respuesta mejor no responden porque ya ven una aceptada y piensan que el problema ya está resuelto

Comment: @wink he añadido una segunda alternativa usando autocomplete que parece que es lo que quieres hacer realmente. Espero que ahora te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alvaro, voy a probarla inmediatamente.

Comment: @wink Suerte. Espero que te sirva y ganarme de nuevo la respuesta aceptada, pero ahora más de manera merecida :)

Comment: Funciona a la perfeccion, gracias @alvaro, ademas de implementar el codigo lo estudiare lo suficiente para aplicarlo por mi mismo en un futuro cercano, mil gracias.  eres un crack xD